# Error while adding library to Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to add a library to android studio and have encountered a few problems. I have looked everywhere and didn't find the solution. [image: Error Screen]

I'd like to add this library (https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/) to my project but when I past this line to build.gradle that error occurs

> ### repositories {
>
> ```
> maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
> ```
>
> }
>
> ### dependencies {
>
> ```
> compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
> compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:layouts:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
> ```
>
> }

Pls help me because I have no idea what to do.

Comment: first u remove that from **build.gradle**. After that `File->project structure->app->Dependencies` add the Libraries _org.lucasr.twowayview:core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar _ i think its correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the statements in the wrong places.
Here's how to fix that:

```
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
```

This line above should be in this `build.gradle`, but inside the `allprojects { repositories { ... } }`, so like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jCenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}
```

Then make sure you removed the `dependencies { ... }` part from this file.
In your `app` folder there is another `build.gradle`. Open that one, and on the bottom you should see a `dependencies { ... }` already (probably with the AppCompat library).

Now insert these two lines inside that `dependency { ... }` clause:

```
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:layouts:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
```